# Catkin cross-compilation of ros-groovy for Zynq ARM target

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, ros-groovy, cross-compilation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm attempting to cross-compile ROS src to a Zynq based ARM system running a version of Angstrom Linux. I've download src (groovy-ros-comm) based on the install from source instructions and created a catkin workspace. I've set up my rostoolchain.cmake file (embedded below) and successfully cross-compiled boost, apr, apr-util and log4cxx.

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /home/adminuser/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_G++_Lite/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc)

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /home/adminuser/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_G++_Lite/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /home/adminuser/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_G++_Lite)

set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH /home/adminuser/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_G++_Lite/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib /home/adminuser/boost-1_50/gcc-4.4-arm /home/adminuser/ros_catkin_ws/ros_ext_deps/lib)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH /home/adminuser/boost-1_50/includes usr/include /home/adminuser/ros_catkin_ws/ros_ext_deps/include)

set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR /home/adminuser/boost-1_50/gcc-4.4-arm/)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM BOTH)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY BOTH)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE BOTH)
set(BOOST_ROOT /home/adminuser/boost-1_50)
set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR /home/adminuser/boost-1_50/includes)
set(Boost_REALPATH TRUE)
set(Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS "1.50" "1.50.0")
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
set(Boost_COMPILER "-gcc44")
set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR /home/adminuser/boost-1_50/includes)
set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS /home/adminuser/boost-1_50/gcc-4.4-arm/)
```

I'm running into problems with the compilation when it comes to rospack as follows.

```
-- Boost version: 1.50.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   filesystem
--   program_options
--   system
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/adminuser/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rospack
==> make -j1 -l1 in '/home/adminuser/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rospack'
Scanning dependencies of target rospack
[ 16%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rospack.dir/src/rospack.cpp.o
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/python2.7" is unsafe for cross-compilation
/home/adminuser/ros_catkin_ws/src/rospack/src/rospack.cpp:30: fatal error: tinyxml.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/rospack.dir/src/rospack.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/rospack.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 717, in build_workspace_isolated
    number=index + 1, of=len(ordered_packages)
  File "./src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 497, in build_package
    install, force_cmake, quiet, last_env, cmake_args, make_args + catkin_make_args
  File "./src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 353, in build_catkin_package
    run_command(make_cmd, build_dir, quiet)
  File "./src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 198, in run_command
    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(proc.returncode, ' '.join(cmd))
CalledProcessError: Command '/home/adminuser/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh make -j1 -l1' returned non-zero exit status 2
<== Failed to process package 'rospack': 
  Command '/home/adminuser/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh make -j1 -l1' returned non-zero exit status 2
Reproduce this error by running:
==> /home/adminuser/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh make -j1 -l1**
```

Do I also need a ARM python library to link against?

I have read that tinyxml was included with the rospack src, but don't see it and the build process complains it can't find it. Do I need to download its src separately?

If the eventual goal is to compile something like the beginner_tutorials to my target do I need rospack? From rospack depends it appears even the simple publisher subscriber depends on rospack. Maybe I'm reading the returned results incorrectly.

Thanks and let me know if any additional detail is needed.

Regards,

Marcus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/68680/catkin-cross-compilation-of-ros-groovy-for-zynq-arm-target/) by [lboltzmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/5542/lboltzmann/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2013-07-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure about the python library, but you will need to cross compile `tinyxml` and provide it on the system library path for `rospack` to find it. `rospack` definitely does not have `tinyxml` embedded internally, we use the system dependency for `tinyxml` in Groovy and Hydro.

You need `rospack` for basically everything because it is used in the command line tools and build system to find packages, plugins, and other things for both building and running.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lboltzmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/5542/lboltzmann/) on 2013-07-26**:
William,

Thanks for the response. I've cross-compiled both python and tinyxml and python is now found. I still have the following error.

/home/adminuser/ros_catkin_ws/src/rospack/src/rospack.cpp:30: fatal error: tinyxml.h: No such file or directory

I have tinyxml.h in the following directory /home/adminuser/ros_catkin_ws/rost_ext_deps/include/tinyxml.

The CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH is set to  /home/adminuser/ros_catkin_ws/rost_ext_deps/include

Any thoughts on why it can't find tinyxml.h?

Thanks again.

Marcus

**Comment by [lboltzmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/5542/lboltzmann/) on 2013-07-26**:
I copied tinyxml.h and tinystr.h into the rospack src directory for the time being and it finds them. Now on to all the non-matching functions errors.  Fun.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-07-26**:
The problem is that one version of TinyXML puts `tinyxml.h` in `<prefix>/include` and another puts it in `<prefix>/include/tinyxml`, so if `rospack` is doing `#include <tinyxml.h>`, you'll have to add `<prefix>/include/tinyxml` to the list of include dirs.

**Comment by [dustingooding](https://answers.ros.org/users/3314/dustingooding/) on 2013-10-22**:
@W I'm in a very similar boat as M. I'm using yujin_tools to cross-compile, but everything else is Catkin/CMake'd. I've created a Catkin package for tinyxml that properly installs headers to /include/tinyxml, and the package advertises "include" and "include/tinyxml". Still not finding it.  Where should this include dir be defined?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-10-22**:
@dustingooding If you provided `include` and `include/tinyxml` to the `catkin_package` call, then that only makes it work for the devel space case. If you have include files which don't install directly to `<prefix>/include` then you need to add that to your include directories using a cmake extras file. Open a new question about "How to export non-standard include directories in catkin" and I'll answer it there, this is getting off topic.

**Comment by [dustingooding](https://answers.ros.org/users/3314/dustingooding/) on 2013-10-22**:
http://answers.ros.org/question/93266/how-to-export-non-standard-include-directories-in-catkin/